# Why was this NAA flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I've flagged this *[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28899619/2307070)*:

> If you clear the Binding list and then add the items will work (based on @sa_ddam213 answer comment)

As not an answer a few days ago. Two reviewers leaved comment seems to think the same as me but my NAA flag have been disputed. Is there a way to know why? If anyone think that I shouldn't have flagged it, could I have an explanation in order to not repeat my mistake?

---

I mean, this answer is just a disguised comment upvote trying to get kudos in place of sa_ddam213, isn't it?

Comment: How is it not an answer to the question?  Short answers aren't Not An Answer.  If you think that it's in incorrect answer, a low quality answer, insufficiently explained, etc. then you can downvote, but it doesn't merit deletion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since OP commented about it being the solution to the issue, I can't see how it can be considered NAA.

[When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer])

> What not to flag
>
> Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a bad answer, but it is still an answer.